# Does Second Chance work in car?

Tags: dead-island

In Dead Island, Purna has a [Survival](http://deadisland.wikia.com/wiki/Purna_Skill_Trees#Survival_Tree) skill called Second Chance (bottom left) which has a chance of instantly reviving Purna upon death. When a player dies in a car, unlike outside of cars, the player dies instantaneously with no chance to be revived. Can the Second Chance skill keep a vehicle-occupant alive, in this situation where a medkit otherwise couldn't?

Comment: Without official word, this one will be hard to test - you'd have to level up Purna far enough to unlock at least the 10% chance and then a) die often enough to get that 1 on a d10 and b) also survive whatever happens once you're revived in the car, which I think is the trickier part. I suspect if a) is possible then you'd probably die again in the car, given Dead Island's quirks. I don't have a Purna on the PC, but if I spin one up I may come back with some proof.

Comment: I've never seen it happen, but it's been so long that I don't remember if I ever specced into it in the first place. If you could edit the value to 100%...